# Undefined method '<' for [0, 0] :Array <NoMethodError>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am beginner of Ruby programming. My program is count number of even length of words in a given string. But it's shows the following Error

**Undefined method '<' for [0, 0] :Array**

Here is My code

```
def even(words, n)
   i = 0, m = 0
   while i < n do
       count = count + words[i].length
       if count%2 == 0 then
          m = m + 1
       end
       i = i + 1
  end
  return m
end
prinnt "Enter The String:"
s = gets.chomp
words = s.split()
n = words.length
x = even(words, n)
puts x
```

Comment: Replace `words = s.split()` with `words = s.split("")` otherwise your input wont get split up by character

Answer (score 4):

I think your problem is here

```
i = 0, m = 0
```

make it

```
i = 0
m = 0
```

Edit:

Also like Kai König said, if you call it like that it means

```
" now's  the time".split        #=> ["now's", "the", "time"]
```

http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-split

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I'd do it:

```
'this is a string'.split.select{ |w| w.size % 2 == 0 }.size # => 3
```

Applying to `gets`:

```
gets.chomp.split.select{ |w| w.length % 2 == 0 }.size
```

Answer (score 1):

The others have already explained to you what the *immediate* error is in your code. However, the bigger problem is that your code is just not idiomatic Ruby code.

Idiomatic code would look something like this:

```
puts gets.split.map(&:length).count(&:even?)
```

And, as you can see, there is simply no way that you *could* even make a mistake such as the one you made.

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
 def even(words, n)
     i = 0
     m = 0
     count = 0
      while i < n do
        count = count + words[i].length
        if count%2 == 0 then m = m + 1 end
        i = i + 1
      end
      return m
      end
      print "Enter The String:"
      s = gets.chomp
      words = s.split("")
      n =  words.length
      #p n 
      x = even(words, n)
      puts x
```